# `bibtex` conference item?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I would like to write a document with the list of all scientific publications : articles / book / oral communications ...

I store all my bibliography with `bibtex`, thus there is no problem for articles or books. But is there a way to manage oral communications or seminar ?

If so, it will be easy to output all my communications (articles, oral, poster ...) using a combination of `bibtex`/`natbib`/`bibtopic`.

Comment: What about `@inProceedins`?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? If no other entry type fits your needs, you could always use the `@misc` type and use its `howpublished` field to provide information such as `Private communication`, `seminar`, or whatever else may be appropriate for some item you wish to reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@InProceedings` entry type:

```
@InProceedings{citekey,
  author =   {},
  title =    {},
  OPTcrossref =  {},
  OPTkey =   {},
  OPTbooktitle = {},
  OPTpages =     {},
  OPTyear =      {},
  OPTeditor =    {},
  OPTvolume =    {},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  OPTseries =    {},
  OPTaddress =   {},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  OPTorganization = {},
  OPTpublisher = {},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}
```

`OPT....` fields are optional. You can use `note` or `annote` to store the kind of contribution (poster, oral, ...). Remember to remove the `OPT` to use it.

Comment: This is a good solution. I use `booktitle` for the name of the conference and also `year`.